# Detox Testing a React Native (Expo) + PouchDB App

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, expo, pouchdb, detox

We are currently working on a React Native app using Expo and are trying to get Detox (E2E Testing) working in our environment. We have spent a lot of time pinpointing where the issue is. The most likely contender seems to be that pouchDB is set up to be live syncing with our database:

```
LocalDB.sync(RemoteDB, {live: true, retry: true})
  .on('change', onChange)
```

and because of this, detox is waiting for certain network requests to finish that we really don't want detox to wait for:

```
Sync App State: Waiting for network requests to finish.:
```

Our tests are running fine without syncing. In our detox tests we've tried blocking that url in our beforeAll & beforeEach blocks with the following:

```
await device.setURLBlacklist(['.*(OUR_IP_THAT_COUCH_IS_SYNCING_WITH).*'])
```

But this on top of the fact that detox doesn't officially support Expo, requiring multiple restarts to open the app, makes it hard to debug.

If anyone has any ideas about this, any help is greatly appreciated!